# CSS Flex Box: How to vertically align "flex items" to middle without losing flex item height?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid-system

Currently my "flex" items look like this (vertically aligned: top)...

```
 _____________________________________
   1

 _____________________________________
   2

 _____________________________________
   3

 _____________________________________
   4

 _____________________________________
```

My Goal is to make them look like this (vertically aligned: middle)...

```
 _____________________________________

   1
 _____________________________________

   2
 _____________________________________

   3
 _____________________________________

   4
 _____________________________________
```

### My requirements:

- The flex container must stay at 100% in height
- The flex items must stay 25% in height (equaling 100%, which is its default anyway).
- The flex items must be vertically centered.
- This must be responsive and be smart enough to stay in the middle per device (so no line-height/padding)

http://jsfiddle.net/oneeezy/p4XtA/

**HTML**

```
<!-- Flex Box -->
<section>

    <!-- Flex Items -->
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>

</section>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Flex Box */
section { padding: 1em; background: black; display: flex; flex-flow: column; height: 100%; justify-content: space-around; }

/* Flex Items */
div { border-top: 1px solid #ccc; background: #f2f2f2; height: 25%; }
div:first-child { border-top: 1px solid transparent; }
div:hover { background: white; }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but can't you just do:

**HTML (Slim)**

```
.container
  .item 1
  .item 2
  .item 3
  .item 4
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
.item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display:flex; 
  align-items:center;
  border-bottom:2px solid #e8e288;
}
```

Here's a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/skube/pen/dRmKxW)

Answer (score 9):

To vertical align content of flexbox child, you will need to apply some other techniques.

I believe there will be content there , wrapped in tag, You can then again use `flex` and set child in `margin:auto;`
**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/p4XtA/2/)**

---

CSS updated :

```
/* Flex Box */
 section {
    padding: 1em;
    background: black;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
/* Flex Items */
 div {
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    height: 25%;
    display:flex;/* be a flexbox too */
}
div:first-child {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}
div:hover {
    background: white;
}
p { /* or any child of flex box used */
    margin:auto;/* here center/middle align */
}
```

HTML structure :

```
<!-- Flex Box -->
<section>
    <!-- Flex Items , Flex Box themselves -->
    <div>
        <p style="width:100%;/* to fill entire width*/">1</p> <!-- Flex Items  -->
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>2</p><!-- Flex Items  -->
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>3</p><!-- Flex Items  -->
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>4</p><!-- Flex Items  -->
    </div>
</section>
```

---

**Maybe a fallback** with `display:table` , can be usefull : **[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/p4XtA/5/)**

```
/* fall back IE8 ie */
html, body, section {
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
section {
    display:table;
}
section > div {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

/* Flex Box */
 section {
    padding: 1em;
    background: black;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
/* Flex Items */
 section > div {
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    height: 25%;
    display:flex;
}
section > div:first-child {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}
section > div:hover {
    background: white;
}
p {
    margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: @MrRioku You are Welcome. flex is very nice, it still needs falbacks. here display:table/table-cell would do for a start in older browser http://jsfiddle.net/p4XtA/5/

Comment: yes, i agree. I was actually thinking about attempting to use my grid system to put in place for a fallback but come to think of it tables (though it kills me to say this) would be a perfect fallback solution for the flexbox. Excellent work my friend.

Comment: seems you can also remove height: 25% from section > div and replace with flex: 1; and that will divide them up evenly.

Comment: exactly :) this the way :)

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is not really related to the so-called flex-box, in fact what you want to align is the **content of the div** (not the `div`), so just use some trick to align it normarlly. Here is one of the tricks:

```
div:before {
  content:'';
  height:100%;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/p4XtA/3/)

Comment: Tricky! But still a bit of a hack- I'm not complaining, i think it's brilliant.. but I'd imagine Flex Box would have something to control this sort of thing?

Comment: It is not a hack, it is CSS :) For flexox child, just use margin:auto;

Comment: touche` haha.... but seriously though. The makers of flex don't have something for this? I've been trying to use "the flex methods" for a few days now and have gotten close but no cigar

Comment: @MrRioku of course, it can just control the **flex item** but not the **inner content of the flex item**.

Answer (score 1):

This is the **Flex**-way of solving your problem:

### HTML

```
<div style="height:300px;"> <!-- Just to test/change the height of <section> element -->
<!-- Flex Box -->
<section>
    <!-- Flex Items -->
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>

</section>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
/* Flex Box */
section {
    padding: 1em;
    background: black;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    height:100%;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

/* Flex Items */
/* Child selector(>) is used to select <div> elements inside <section> element*/
section > div {
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    height: 25%;

    /* Added code */
    display: flex;       /* Gives inner div flex display */
    align-items: center; /* Centers the div in the cross axis */
    /**************/
}
section > div:first-child {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}
section > div:hover {
    background: white;
}
```