# Flex items 25% height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a column that automatically fills its height using flexbox, and within this I have 4 items that I want to each be 25% of the height of their container.

I've created this fiddle to show my current code: https://jsfiddle.net/fc66rfo3/1/
I want the blue boxes on the right to each be 25% of the height of their yellow container.

I've been using this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23442782/3909886 to try and make my code work, but the items just don't seem to want to flow as I want them to.

My main CSS trying to affect the heights looks like this:

```
.resources-links {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.col-1of1 {
    height: 25%;
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: `flex:1` is a useful alternative. But `height` and `flex-basis` can also work. Here's why your `height:25%` isn't working: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry. Just remove "**height: 25%;display: flex;**" and add "**flex: 1;**".

CSS:

**Remove this**

```
.col-1of1 {
  height: 25%;
  display: flex;
}
```

**Add this**

```
.col-1of1 {
  flex: 1;
}
```